# Do Flyway support zipped scripts

Tags: database-migration, flyway

I am introducing Flyway in our company and I want to know if it is possible to flyway support scripts in tar.gz or zip. Our dump is huge (600MB) and even if I dump only the necessary tables it is still big enough (100MB). Github only supports files lower than 50MB, so I can't commit this baseline.

Or am I doing something wrong using the production dump as a baseline?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't put all the production *data* in the baseline. I'd put the production *schema* in the baseline and seed the database with a defined set of test data afterwards. The question is, why would you want/need the production data in your migrations?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a tool like [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/). If not, it's certainly possible to do what you want using a custom `MigrationResolver`. You can have an arbitrary number of compressed files (to stay under the 50MB limit) and read them from the classpath (or a filesystem location). You might even be able to use DbUnit in your custom resolver to simplify things. What I've done before is to split bulky tasks into a bunch of smaller `ResolvedMigration` tasks each with a minor version number so that it's much easier to reason about what's happening, especially when things fail. It's important that the process of generating version numbers is fully deterministic, otherwise your migrations might fail in strange ways. You might need to do some extra work to make sure that your `ResolvedMigration` object is lazy, so that you don't end up decompressing hundreds of megabytes every time Flyway runs, whether there's any work to be done or not.